# Как правильно организовать базу данных

Tags: база-данных, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
У отелей есть много услуг (например трансфер, парковка, интернет и т.д.), так же у каждой комнаты в отеле могут быть разные услуги (минибар, балкон, вид на море/парк и т.д.).
Получается что объект (отель или комната) предоставляют услуги. Связь многие ко многим.

Таблица будет выглядеть примерно так (составной внешний ключ)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как связать модели?

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :service_in_object
  has_many :hotels, through: :service_in_object
end

class ServiceInObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :object #хмм
  belongs_to :service
end

class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rooms

  has_many :service_in_object
  has_many :service, through: :service_in_object
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :hotel

  has_many :service_in_object
  has_many :service, through: :service_in_object
end
```

Как правильно это организовать?

Comment: Не надо дополнительно закладывать в вопрос то, чего там не было. Полиморф тут не единственное возможное решение. Правку заголовка откатил.

Comment: Спорить не буду, есть и другие решения. Полиморфная связь сама по себе в других технологиях считается антипаттерном. Просто object_id и object_type поддалкивают именно к реализации именно полиморфной связи. С откатом согласен, тем более я сам переделал таблицу. Если кто-то предложит альтернативу с удовольствием ознакомлюсь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас получается полиморфная связь, которую нужно ввести при помощи ключевого слова polymorphic. Если не возражаете, я немного переделаю таблицу service_in_objects, чтобы избавиться от object - не очень хорошее название, давайте сделаем serviceable. Миграции для таблиц могут выглядеть следующим образом

```
create_table :hotels, comment: "Оттели" do |t|
  t.string  :title, comment: "Название"
end

create_table :rooms, comment: "Комнаты" do |t|
  t.string  :title, comment: "Номер"
  t.integer :hotel_id, comment: "Внешний ключ для связи с оттелем"
end

create_table :services, comment: "Сервисы" do |t|
  t.string  :title, comment: "Название"
end

create_table :service_in_objects, comment: "Промежуточная cвязующая таблица" do |t|
  t.integer :service_id, comment: "Внешний ключ для связи с сервисом"
  t.integer :serviceable_id, comment: "Внешний ключ для связи с оттелем или комнатой"
  t.string  :serviceable_type, comment: "Внешний ключ для связи с оттелем или комнатой"
end
```

Тогда модели с учетом полиморфной связи через промежуточную таблицу service_in_objects могут принять следующий вид

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :service_in_objects

  has_many \
    :rooms, 
    through: :service_in_objects, 
    source: :serviceable, 
    source_type: 'Room'
  has_many \
    :hotels, 
    through: :service_in_objects, 
    source: :serviceable, 
    source_type: 'Hotel'
end

class ServiceInObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :serviceable, polymorphic: true
end

class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms

  has_many :service_in_objects, as: :serviceable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :services, through: :service_in_objects
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotel

  has_many :service_in_objects, as: :serviceable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :services, through: :service_in_objects
end
```

Убедиться в том, что полиморфная связь работает, можно при помощи сидов (db/seed.rb):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('TRUNCATE hotels');
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('TRUNCATE rooms');
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('TRUNCATE services');
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('TRUNCATE service_in_objects');

services = [{title: 'internet'}, {title: 'parking'}, {title: 'service1'}]
Service.create services

hotels = [{title: 'mariot'}, {title: 'hilton'}]
Hotel.create hotels
Hotel.all.each do |h|
  h.rooms.create [{title: '1'}, {title: '2'}, {title: '4'}]
  h.services << [Service.all.sample, Service.all.sample]
  h.save
end

Room.all.each do |r|
  r.services << [Service.all.sample, Service.all.sample]
  r.save
end
```

В реальном проекте настоятельно рекомендуется покрыть тестами хотя бы связи - у вас примере идущем с вопросом явные ошибки с единственным/множественным числом - тесты вас сильно выручат на данном этапе. Напортачить в связях не сложно, модели будут работать и со сломанными связями, только воспользоваться ими не получится и при этом сообщения об ошибках на сломанных связях не совсем очевидны.

Обратите внимание:

Связь **belongs_to** - всегда **единственное** число, **has_many** - всегда **множественное** число.

Название **таблиц** - всегда **множественное** число, название **моделей** - всегда **единственное** число.

Comment: `objectable` это ещё хуже. `serviceable` хотя бы, "обслуживаемое".

Comment: Да, пожалуй, сейчас поменяю.

Comment: А как то можно ограничить данную связь? В том смысле что может получиться так что у Номера будет сервис Парковка, хотя понятно что едва ли такое возможно.

Comment: Можно в Service добавить флажок is_only_room и ориентироваться на него, добавива в модель Service коллбэк или валидацию, которая предотвратит сохранение определенного сервиса. Не уверен, что самое элегантное решение, просто первое что пришло в голову.

Comment: @Павел полиморфы тем и плохи, что могут быть приассоциированы к чему угодно. В такой модели данных парковка может быть ассоциирована с номером, или даже с другим сервисом (oops!). Целостность и осмысленность данных, таким образом, контролируется только приложением.